# Keep tooltip (title attribute) updated while mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, title

I want to display how much time has passed since the last time the page was reloaded.

```
<li id="last-update-title" onmouseover="updateTimeToolTip()">Some Text here</li>
```

And here is the updateTimeToolTip() function that I have

```
function updateTimeToolTip() {
    document.getElementById('last-update-title').title = customFormatTimeSecondsAgo(updateTime);
};

function customFormatTimeSecondsAgo(date) {
    var result = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
    if (result <= 1) return "Updated: Just now";
    return "Updated: " + result + " seconds ago";
};
```

These functions working fine now to calculate the time. It displays the time passed when I hover on the text. However, the title attribute will not change while the mouse is over it which is normal but I think it would be nice if I could make it keep updating while the mouse is over the text. Is there any way I can achieve this without using any external JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try and update the native browser tooltip if I were you, I would try something more custom like this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <style>

      #last-update-title{
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      #tooltip{
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        display:none;
      }

      #tooltip.show{
        display:inherit;
      }

    </style>
    <body>

      <div id="last-update-title" onmouseover="showToolTip('show');" onmouseout="showToolTip('');">
        Some Text here
        <div id="tooltip"></div>
      </div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function showToolTip(show){
        document.getElementById('tooltip').className = show;
      }

      var startDate = new Date();
      setInterval(function(){
          document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML = customFormatTimeSecondsAgo(startDate);
      }, 1000)

      function customFormatTimeSecondsAgo(date) {
          var result = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
          if (result <= 1) return "Updated: Just now";

          return "Updated: " + result + " seconds ago";
      };


    </script>
  </html>
```

This avoids problems around how different browsers render tooltips, and also will get around the tooltip not updating dynamically as you want it to.

Comment: Yeah this is a great option for dynamic tooltip without using any JQuries. Great alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var updateInterval;
$(function() {
    $('#last-update-title').on('mouseover', function() {
        updateInterval = setInterval(updateTimeToolTip, 10);
    });

    $('#last-update-title').on('mouseout', function() {
        clearInterval(updateInterval);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good approach however it's not working as smoothly as I want it to be. It works if the I move the cursor a little but if the cursor stays still, it won't update

Comment: I updated the interval time to be 10 instead of 1000. Maybe that will work better for you.

Comment: No it's still not the way I want it to be. I guess native title attribute doesn't really allow you to update its content

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a something that acts similar to a clock i recommend using the interval function, like so:

```
<li id="last-update-title" onmouseover="function(){setInterval(updateTimeToolTip(), 3000);}">Some Text here</li>
```